# Кодирование строки PHP

Tags: php

Есть у меня такой текст

```
Сезон охоты открыт! Возьмите снайперскую винтовку или базуку и начните охоту
```

Как сделать на php чтоб он выглядел вот так

```
%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD+%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82!+%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `urlencode`:

```
$s = 'Сезон охоты открыт! Возьмите снайперскую винтовку или базуку и начните охоту';
$encoded = urlencode($s);
```

Строка $encoded будет содержать нужный вам результат.

Comment: `;` забыли. Кодировка файла/строки должна быть UTF-8.

Comment: @Visman Спасибо за замечание, исправил.